# Hibernate не работает batch insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

**persistence.xml**

```
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="5"/>
    <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
```

**Модель**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "id")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "msg_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "msg_seq_gen", sequenceName = "msg_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Setter
    private String text;
}
```

**Транзакция**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void run(String... strings) {

int batchSize = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    em.persist(message);

    if (i > 0 && i % batchSize == 0) {
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
     }
  }
}
```

**логи :**

```
Hibernate: call next value for msg_seq
Hibernate: call next value for msg_seq
Hibernate: call next value for msg_seq
Hibernate: call next value for msg_seq
Hibernate: call next value for msg_seq
Hibernate: insert into Message (text, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Message (text, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Message (text, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Message (text, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Message (text, id) values (?, ?)
```

Вопрос, как настроить хайбернейт для того, чтобы использовался батч-инсерт/апдейт ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете `EntityManager` для добавления объекта в БД, но он относится к JPA, а не конкретно к Hibernate, хотя настройки батчинга относятся к внутренностям Hibernate.

Попробуйте использовать объект `Session`.

```
Session session = ...
int batchSize = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    session.persist(message);

    if (i > 0 && i % batchSize == 0) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

[Пример из офф. документации](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `allocationSize` увеличить до 5(по умолчанию стоит 50). Возможно, что он каждый раз идет к базе за `ID`.
Если увеличить `allocationSize` он  зарезервирует 5 id и не будет каждый раз идти в базу.